# ESRI JavaScript API 3.8 Locator: SyntaxError {log: undefined, stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding, syntax

I am having issues trying to set up a geocoder/locator on my server.  I keep getting an error **SyntaxError {log: undefined, stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}**, but I can't seem to figure out why.  I tried exploring the error message, but I don't get much good information out of it.

I have tried using ESRI's geocoder widget then created my own set up using the locator service.  I have checked my address string, and I believe it should be passing correctly over to the server.

If I am understanding the error message right, it is saying there is a token "<" somewhere that shouldn't be there, but I cannot find it.

Other info...  I am running version 9.3.1 for my server, using the JavaScript API 3.8 that ESRI hosts, and created an address locator on my server using street centerlines for the area I am mapping.

Has anyone run into this issue before or have suggestions for me?  Right now, I am just trying to center the map on the location.  Once I get that done, I can worry about all the other stuff.

My code for the locator is below.[Here](https://www.cartotronics.com/UTC_Viewer_LouisvilleKY/) is my development site.

```
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
locator = new Locator(singleFieldGeocodeURL);
//add handler for completion
locator.on("address-to-locations-complete", showResults);

//trying to find the error
locator.on("error", function (error) {
    errorObject = error;
    console.log("error" + error);

});


//add handler for button click
on(dom.byId('locate'), 'click', function () {

    console.log(dom.byId('address').value);

    map.graphics.clear();
    var address = {
        "SingleLine": dom.byId('address').value
    };

    locator.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;

    var options = {
        address: { street: address },
        outFields: ["Loc_name"]

    };
    locator.addressToLocations(options);

});

function showResults(evt) {
    console.log("in show results");
    var candidate;
    var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    symbol.setStyle(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE);
    symbol.setColor(new Color([153, 0, 51, 0.75]));

    var geom;
    arrayUtils.event(evt.addresses, function (candidate) {
        console.log(candidate.score);
        if (candidate.score > 80) {
            console.log(candidate.location);
            var attributes = {
                address: candidate.address,
                score: candidate.score,
                locatorName: candidate.attributes.Loc_name
            };
            geom = candidate.location;
            var graphic = new Graphic(geom, symbol, attributes, null);
            map.graphics.add(graphic);

            return false;

        }
    });

    if (geom !== undefined) {
        map.centerAndZoom(geom, 12);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are providing an invalid url to your locator service in your code.

```
"https://www.cartotronics.com/ArcGIS93/services/UTC_Viewers/Louisville_AlphaNumeric_Ranges/GeocodeServer"

//should be

"https://www.cartotronics.com/ArcGIS93/rest/services/UTC_Viewers/Louisville_AlphaNumeric_Ranges/GeocodeServer"
```

just as an aside, it would have been substantially less painful to help you debug the error related to your locator if you had provided more than a mysterious variable name in your code snippet or a link to an app without code that had already been minified.

Comment: Thanks!  I do apologize for leaving my code minified.  I totally forgot I had it set up to minify when I was saving it. I didn't even think it was related to my URL, but it is the simple mistakes that get me.

Comment: no worries at all Branco. glad to help  :)